# Diamond pattern in digital form

Tags: patterns

I would like to get jpg, png, or similar file that contains blue diamond pattern similar to the one in the following picture:

[image]

Also, I would like to know if such pattern is pattented, ir protected in some other way, that would stop me from using it.

I appreciate your time spent on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [argyle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argyle_%28pattern%29). It's been around since the 1500's and has no restrictions on it.

Comment: I didn't know this, but like [_Scotia_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotia), this literally means ["Land of the Gaels"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Argyle) i.e. Ireland.